# Roland MicroCube GX MOD: bluetooth aux in

Tags: amplifier, bluetooth

I own a Roland MicroCube GX guitar amplifier (see https://www.roland.com/global/products/micro_cube_gx/); I'm pretty pleased with it.

This particular model has, in addition to the guitar input jack, an extra 3.5mm input jack (labeled AUX IN) that allows the user to connect an external input source so that you can hear both your guitar and, for instance, a backing track. This is particularly useful for studying and practicing parts.

Now I would like to be able to send this external signal via bluetooth. I've been looking around and found that the XY-BT-Mini ([https://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Lossless-Decoder-Amplifier-XY-BT-Mini/dp/B07P2WJSYY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P2WJSYY)) might be a good option, but I have two questions regarding the best way to connect the module so that it is installed inside the amplifier with minor modifications to it.

1. Connecting the signal itself: Can I connect the output of the module (i.e., the R-G-L pins) to the corresponding pins on the built-in 3.5mm input jack? I guess this means that both inputs (the jack and the input from the bluetooth module) will be connected in parallel; is that ok or even safe?
2. Powering the module: the amp itself is powered via a AC/DC transformer that delivers 5.7V/2A (so it says on the label). How would you go about taking just 5V from that? (as the module works between 3.5V and 5V)

Thanks in advance for all your help. And please, if you come up with a different way to achieve this, let me know!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Connecting the signal itself: Can I connect the output of the module (i.e., the R-G-L pins) to the corresponding pins on the built-in 3.5mm input jack? I guess this means that both inputs (the jack and the input from the bluetooth module) will be connected in parallel; is that ok or even safe?

It should be fine. My caution would be to check if the jack socket shorts the inputs to ground when the plug is removed. (This would be done to eliminate hum when nothing is plugged in and the trick is probably employed on the guitar input already.) I would solder onto the tip, ring and ground connections and check if it works. If not try inserting an empty 3.5 mm jack to force disconnect the ground contacts.

If you want to prevent a plugged in device fighting with the Bluetooth module then add a 1k resistor into the tip and into the ring leads.

> 2. Powering the module: the amp itself is powered via a AC/DC transformer that delivers 5.7 V / 2 A (so it says on the label). How would you go about taking just 5V from that? (as the module works between 3.5 V and 5 V).

Two options:

- Use an LDO (low drop-out) voltage regulator (with the recommended decoupling capacitors).
- Series connect a couple of silicon diodes between the 5.7 V supply and the Bluetooth module. They'll drop 0.7 V each. I'd check the open-circuit voltage of the 5.7 V supply though to see if it goes much higher than 5.7 V when unloaded. If it does the LDO solution would be less risky.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I'll try everything out as you suggest and be back to rate your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm back after doing some research. Do you think I can use a DC-DC step down module, such as the LM2596 instead of the LDO voltage regulator? In terms of costs the difference seems negligible, and it seems like a complete solution for powering the bluetooth module. What do you think? Thanks again for your time.